# if else statement along with try catchblock throwing an error

Tags: java, try-catch

```
//Program to Check the given Number is an odd or even number
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenOddNo { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number to check \"Even or Odd\" number");
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        String j =getNo(k);
        System.out.println(j);
        sc.close();
    }

    static public String getNo(int n) // Throwing an error *This method must   return a result of type String*
    {
        try {
            if(n%2==0) {
                return n+" is an Even number";
            }
            else
                return n+" is an Odd Number";
        }catch(ArithmeticException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

}
```

Comment: You need to add a default return either in a finally block or outside your try/catch

Comment: your catch block needs to contain a return statement, or you must put it after the catch block, to make sure that every possible flow has a return statement

Comment: Just remove that try-catch block. The code in the try block never throws that exception anyway.

Comment: What ArithmeticException do you expect here to catch ???

Answer (score 2):

What happens if your try block throws an `ArithmeticException`? So you are missing a return statement. You have to add one, preferable as a default one after the `try-catch`.

Comment: Thank You Murat K, sshashank124, Stultuske, I have learnt by an error... Thanks a lot. Even though there would be no accurance of the excdption I have just added the try-catch block to learn as a beginner.